# Drag html element outside electron window to copy local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, drag-and-drop, electron

I am planning to realize a music player with [electron](http://electron.atom.io/). It will list music from the user’s hard drive.
Is it possible to define a drag’n’drop behavior so that I can drag a html element, e.g. `<span>Artist – Title</span>` outside the electron window onto the user’s desktop to copy the actual file?

File is stored here: `~/music/Artist-Title.mp3`.

When drag’n’dropping the `span`from my electron window onto the desktop a copy should be made: `~/Desktop/Artist-Title.mp3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example:

Put into `main.js` and copy an icon to be shown while dragging (`yourAppDir/img/icon/folder.png)`:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filePath) => {
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: filePath,
    icon: 'img/icon/folder.png'
  })
})
```

Put into `renderer.js`, and set the path to the file you want to drop out:

```
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer

document.getElementById('drag').ondragstart = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    ipcRenderer.send('ondragstart', '/Users/tim/dev/test/elektron-drag-out-test/img/icon/folder.png')
  }
```

Create the draggable element inside the body tags of `index.html`:

```
...
<body>
  ...
  <a href="#" id="drag" class="draggable">drag item</a>
</body>
...
```

I also created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/timpulver/452670e4a0ec9619a06347ff61c3f60c) for drag in / out.

Another helpful resource: [Electron – Add `webContents.startDrag(item)` API](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/6333)

Comment: is it possible to get target os path name , where files are being dropped ?

Comment: is it possible to know when the item was dropped outside of the electron window?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the API you are looking for.

http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentsstartdragitem

```
remote.getCurrentWebContents().startDrag({
  file: 'path/to/file',
  icon: 'path/to/file/icon',
});
```

Comment: Good starting point! Thanks! But as this is no complete solution I posted another answer.